# MS Chart Control: Drawing and Labeling Line Series below the Chart Area

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, data-visualization

How can I represent different curves in the graph with different names?
I need like this, blue line should     represent AngleM1, Brown line should represent AngleM2 and so on.
All labels must be under x-axis.

Example :

[image: Example]

Comment: Welcome to SO. 
Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and show us your efforts.

Comment: Those are not Labels but LegendItems. If you can get those curves to show in different Series all you need it a) give those Series the right Names and b) Dock the Legend to the Bottom.